# Mixing for Cinema in Home Studio

Tags: post-production, surround-sound, film-mixing, dialnorm

I am preping for a film mix in my small studio and just was calibrating the speakers but with my small monitors i can't reach the SPL required. SO i decided to reference with a DVD dialogue track at various moods and to reach a dialogue level which is comfortable for us and then mix MX and FX around it.

We are primarily planning for DVD release but also planing for a preview show in a nearby cinema hall. SO just wanted to check how my mix levels would be and any checkpoints i have to look for.

Please share your comments and tips.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to produce a proper theater mix in a small studio. It is also usually not a good idea to deliver one common mix for theater, home-theater and two loudspeakers flat screen.

Although your method of using some references tracks to setup levels is not wrong in itself, it is not possible to reproduce the perception of a large theater with a screen in a small home studio.

One option is to book a theater dubstage for a few hours and go there with your mix session, including stems, and have a quick playback of the movie, adjusting the dedicated theater mix as needed.

Comment: yeah, i know the perception won't be matching. now i am planning to prepare some 5.1 stems and also looking for a an affordable dub stage. thanks for the inputs.